# Trailing return types and fallback for Koenig lookup

Tags: c++, return-type, argument-dependent-lookup, trailing-return-type, return-type-deduction

Most of the time, the C++17 inferred return type of a simple member function can be easily transformed to a C++11 trailing return type.

For example, the member function in

```
template<typename T>
struct X
{
    T a;
    auto f() { return frob(a); }
};
```

becomes

```
auto f() -> decltype(frob(a)) { return frob(a); }
```

Considering that `using namespace` is not permitted at top-level scope within a class body, how do you write a trailing return type for the following?

```
namespace widget
{
    template<typename S>
    int froz(S&&);
}

template<typename T>
struct Y
{
    T b;
    auto g() { using namespace widget; return froz(b); }
};
```

(For example, the usage of argument-dependent lookup with a fallback is very common when calling `std::swap`, `std::begin`, `std::end`)

```
template<typename T>
struct Z
{
    T container;
    auto h() { using namespace std; return begin(container); }
};
```

Comment: Why do you need this anyway?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: It's a motivating example for allowing `using namespace` in a class.  That makes life better in a lot of ways, but the others can mostly all be dealt with by just qualifying names here, there, and everywhere.  This example can't.

Comment: And what is the use case of converting inferred return type into equivalent trailing return type? It seems to cause code duplication without much benefit.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Microcontroller targets with compilers still stuck on C++11?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Z
{
    T container;
    auto h() -> decltype(
        [] 
        {
            Z<T>* z;
            using namespace std; return begin(z->container);
        }()

    ) { using namespace std; return begin(container); }
};
```

Comment: That's really quite horrifying, but inventive

Comment: Note that this only works from C++20. In C++17, you can't put a lambda inside an unevaluated expression.

Comment: well... the question was asking for a C++11 solution. Very inventive however.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the nicest workaround I have found, introducing a helper namespace to host the `using namespace` as closely as possible:

```
namespace impl
{
    using namespace std;

    template<typename T>
    struct Z
    {
        T container;
        auto h() -> decltype(begin(container)) { return begin(container); }
    };
}
using impl::Z;
```

To not affect the entire class, it could be use to make Ayxan's idea of using `decltype` on a helper function work in C++11:

```
namespace impl
{
    using namespace std;

    template<typename T>
    auto begin(T&& t) -> decltype(begin(std::forward<T&&>(t)));
}

template<typename T>
struct Z
{
    T container;
    auto h() -> decltype(impl::begin(container)) { using namespace std; return begin(container); }
};
```

Comment: Why not actually use `return impl::begin(container)` instead of `using namespace std; return begin(container)` instead of only using it for type deduction? Like https://rextester.com/SSWTA2870

Comment: @Artyer: `impl::begin` is actually not defined only declared.  It can't be called.

Comment: As in actually define it to just `return begin(std::forward<T>(container))` so it could be

Comment: You certainly can define it but that's more code and more function calls in the actual execution path for future maintenance programmers to worry about.